# no such file to load -- openid/extensions/sreg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid

I'm running ruby 1.8.6 and rails 2.3.2 on Mac OS X 10.5.6.

I'm trying to get ruby script/server to work...

I've waded through mysql and imagemagick installation, and I'm now faced with the following error:

```
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- openid/extensions/sreg (MissingSourceFile)
```

Just prior to getting this error, I had finished substituting "gem" for "require_gem" in an openid-related file...

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Dean Richardson

Comment: Why were you doing the substitution?

Answer (score 3):

gem install openid

Answer (score 1):

Is the open id gem installed?

Comment: Thanks... that ended up being one of the steps to fix my problem, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just install gem **oa-openid**

Source: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/OpenID-and-Google-Apps